# Is there any command line to see the missing files on Linux?

Tags: linux

Is there any command line to see the missing files on Linux. I have a list of files start from 000 to 073 in the terminal folder on MobaXterm. But as you see in the picture below 070 is missing. Thanks

[image]

Comment: missing files, you mean moved to some arbitrary directory or you are talking about deleted files? or maybe you just want a list that warns you, that in this sequential logic, this file is missing?

Comment: yes, I  just want a list that warns me, that in this sequential logic, this file is missing, thanks

Comment: If I suggest a shell script is enough for you? Or you really want a single command?

Comment: I don't have experience with the shell script, a single command on the terminal would be great, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This commands check if a file exists:

```
test -f file
[[ -f file ]]
```

You can echo a message based on the return value of those:

```
test -f file || echo file does not exist
```

To check many files, you can use a `for` loop:

```
for f in {000..073}.mat ; do
    [[ -f $f ]] || echo $f does not exist
done
```

Or as oneliner:

```
for f in {000..073}.mat ; do [[ -f $f ]] || echo $f is missing; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd yourfolder
    for file in {001..099}; do
       [ -e "$file.mat" ] && echo $file.mat || echo "Warning: $file.mat is missing"
    done
```

Change 99 to the number of files you are expecting....

Comment: This gives all files are missing; Warning: 001.mat is missing
Warning: 002.mat is missing
Warning: 003.mat is missing
Warning: 004.mat is missing
Warning: 005.mat is missing
Warning: 006.mat is missing
Warning: 007.mat is missing
Warning: 008.mat is missing
..... thanks

Comment: @kutlus Are you running this in the folder with the files? e.g. cd folderwiththefiles . I tested here and it is working fine.

Comment: Thank you, yes in the folder it worked, but it prints also all the existing files together with the warning for the missing file. For the very large number datasets, I prefer just to print the missing files. But I voted for you, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you know the upper limit of files then:

```
for i in {000..074}
  do
  if [ -f "$i.mat" ]
  then
    echo "$i.mat exists"
  else
    echo "$i.mat doesn't exists"
  fi
done
```

You can modify the `echo` commands according to your wish.

Answer (score 0):

With the `zsh` shell:

```
files=(<->.mat)
expected=({000..073}.mat)

missing=(${expected:|files})
printf ' - %s\n' $missing
```

For files with simple names like that, you could use also use `comm` (here using the ksh, zsh or bash shell):

```
comm -13 <(ls) <(seq -f '%03d.mat' 0 73)
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit, everything is bouncing off my head?